# "offset or count might be near -1>>>1." What does it mean

Tags: java

In java String [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28char%5B%5D,int,int%29), there are few places noted with the following comment:

```
// Note: offset or count might be near -1>>>1.
```

Consider the following example:

```
public String(char value[], int offset, int count) {
    if (offset < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset);
    }
    if (count < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(count);
    }
    // Note: offset or count might be near -1>>>1.
    if (offset > value.length - count) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset + count);
    }
    this.offset = 0;
    this.count = count;
    this.value = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, offset, offset+count);
}
```

As we can see, `offset`, `value.length` and `count` are all `int`, thus the value might be either -1, 0, 1, or any other integers. What does the "near" and ">>>" in the comment means, am I missing something here?

Comment: `-1 >>> 1` is an obfuscated way of saying `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The value `-1>>>1 == 2147483647` is the maximum `int` value you can have in Java.

In other words, `-1>>>1 == Integer.MAX_VALUE`. When you do maths with values close to such limits, you increase your chances of getting unexpected results. For instance, `int a = (-1>>>1); System.out.println(a < a + 1);` prints `false` because of an *integer overflow*, even though one could expect that code to always print `true` since, in pure maths, for any integer `n` it is true that `n < n + 1`.

The author of that piece of code is just explaining his (wise) decision to write

```
if (offset > value.length - count)
```

instead of the *similar-looking-but-not-equivalent*

```
if (offset + count > value.length)
```

This last version could cause an integer overflow, which could be a huge trouble for the code that follows. He is alerting to the fact that there's a possibility that at least one of `offset` or `count` could be a value close to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which increases the possibility of the overflow.

With the first version (the one used in the source code for String you mention), there can never be an overflow: you know for sure that both `offset` and `count` are positive or 0 because of previous checks, and `value.length` is also positive or 0 because the length of an array is always positive or 0 in Java, so no overflow problems can happen!

In addition to documenting the choice, the author warns other developers (including his future self) that there's a very specific reason for that line to be written the way it is, to avoid anyone who is tempted to replace it with the (possibly more natural looking) second, incorrect version from introducing a bug.

Comment: that is well thought through from the author who wrote that code.

Comment: just curious, why don't the author wrote "offset or count might be near Integer.MAX_VALUE" instead? though Integer.MAX_VALUE is vague, at least that would be easier to comprehend. After all, the point of the comment is to warn future developers of possible Integer overflow if the code is changed.

Comment: @zynick: "easier to comprehend" is relative, based on where you come from, what your experiences you have. And keep in mind: this is not public documentation that went through a documentation team to optimize. This is simply a note that one JDK developer wrote for all future developers that touch that code. It's informal and not necessarily the best possible way to put it.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) for explanation about the `>>>` operator:

> The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the
>   leftmost position

Say you have:

```
int a = -1;
a = a >>> 1;
System.out.println(a);
```

Then `a` will be 2147483647 (Which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`)

**Why?**

Since the  `>>>`operator fills zeros and only zeros no matter positive and negative number. So, for example, if you have:

`12 >>> 2`

(00000000 00000000 00000000 000011 00 >>> 2) then the result is 3.

(Which is 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011).

So, if you'll do:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-1>>>1));
```

This will print:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111
```

And of course, converting it to decimal, this is 2147483647.

*As @BrunoReis (+1) explained in his answer, the reason for doing this is to prevent possible integer overflow problems.*

Comment: For better understanding you should explain what's two's complement number representation. Right now it's not obvious why 1111111111111111111111111111111 is -1 and 0111111111111111111111111111111 is max value.

Comment: thanks for explaining how the bit works in integer, I have accidentally left that in my college